# H2 database column size

Tags: java, schema, h2

This is a followup question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274119/column-data-type/12274611).

Is the size of a given text column in a table, eg varchar(32) stored in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table, column `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but why don't you just use java.sql.DatabaseMetaData?

Comment: Very good point :) I think my mind was a bit confused and I didnt really take in exactly what the `getColumns()` function does. I'm guessing that `COLUMN_SIZE` would be what I need.

Comment: Yes, `COLUMN_SIZE` is the correct column. Because `DatabaseMetaData` is part of the JDBC API specification, it is better standardized than the table/view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, which is 'only' part of the ANSI SQL specification.